# I want regular expression for age field in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var text6 = document.getElementById("text6").value;
    var regularExpression1 = /^[1-9]?[0-9]{1}$|^100$/;

  if (!text6.match(regularExpression1)){
          alert("Please enter Valid Age");
          return false;
      }
```

This code is not working properly

Comment: You're trying to use **Regular Expression** to verify an **integer** value?

Comment: Ya right but in database its a string

Comment: What exactly is not working? In which test cases it fails? What you're trying to validate?

Comment: I am trying to validate age text field, if i give input as string then it takes the string that i dont want, i only want is int value between 1 to 100

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a regexp. Use this function for checking whether something is a number

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

And for your case

```
function isIntegerBetween0And100(n) {
  return isNumber(n) && n>0 && n<=100 && n%1===0;
}
```

Much faster :)

Comment: And that meets the requirements how?  Looking at the regex, the requirements are a value between 0 and 100, without decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is using `|` but without `()`.

`/(^[1-9]?[0-9]{1}$|^100$)/` would work, but it could be better. This expression can be simplified to `/^([1-9]?\d|100)$/`, i.e. there's no need to repeat `^` or `$`, `[0-9]` can be `\d`, and `{1}` is always unnecessary.

I'm not sure regex is best for validating an age, I'm not sure why you can't just simplify it to `/^\d{1,3}$/`.  Things can be older than 100, even people.

I would also validate fields using `/regex/.test()` instead of `string.match(/regex/)`.

If you have an age range limit, then test that in 'normal code' not regex, it would be easier to follow and modify (if your upper limit changes).

Comment: your regex fails when testing james bond's agent number : `/^\d{1,3}$/.test('007') === true;`. And it's wrong, since '007' is not a valid integer

Comment: @gion_13: 007 is a valid integer.  Where are you plucking these limitations from?  I also didn't say `/^\d{1,3}$/` was a regex for all valid integers, either.  7, 07, 007 and 0007 are all equivalent, I don't know why anybody would enforce a user to adhere to any specific convention, the more annoying your system, fewer will use it.

Comment: easy, don't get so personal. I wasn't trying to be mean, I was just pointing out that you could improve your answer. If you don't it's your choice. In this context where you need to validate an age (not an integer, sry), I caught an error in your answer. I'm not trying to enforce anyone to adhere to my (or any other) specific convention because I thought that an age cannot begin with a zero (if you want to say that you're 037 years old, be my guest).

Comment: @gion_13: Ha ha. Days of the month don't start with a zero either, but they're often written that way for some reason, it's just zero-padding.  Probably originating from fixed-width-font displays, but totally artificial, many systems wrongly insist that those leading zeros are entered (by the user that is), much to my annoyance.  An age is a number and as such can start with a zero, it's unnecessary, but in decimal, you're just saying zero hundreds, zero tens and 7 for 007, to be practical, it's not incorrect to allow somebody to input that if they wanted to.